# a 4A 3s(11.1v) 30c lipo battery will it blow up my arduino?

Tags: arduino, lipo

The lipo has a high discharge of 4A 30C. i read that arduino can only handle 2A does this mean it uses 2A out of 4A or is there some kind of system to limit the amp draw?

Answer (score -1):

You're good to go.  You can use this.

Your battery is rated, not at 4A, but at **4Ah**, meaning it has enough energy in it to provide 4A for 1 hour, or 1A for 4 hours, or 2A for 2 hours, etc.  As long as your Arduino can handle the voltage (some models are 5V only) then you can use it.

Your Arduino is rated to draw 2A.  Your battery, especially if it's a LiPO, is capable of providing much more than this.  A good battery with these ratings you've given can be capable of delivering as much as 100A in short bursts.

Your battery has a *capacity* rating on it.  Usually LiPO batteries can provide current for short periods at least ten times their capacity rating.

Comment: Technically, he doesn't know what he's doing.  But let's tell him that he's good to go.  Why not.

Comment: No he doesn't know what he's doing.  Not at all.  But he can use this battery with his Arduino, provided that he hooks everything up right and doesn't do something stupid.

Comment: LOL thats true, i am much of coding student didn't really knew much about lipo's but now got things cleared, i am trying to learn electronics with help of arduino

Comment: Whatever you do, don't hook things up backwards.  LiPOs can detonate rather violently.